# Dependance of number of harmonics from force of collision

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves, harmonics

I recently found out that if hit something hard, it will produce all harmonics, but if hit with less and less force firstly low harmonics will disappear firstly and only high will stay. Why so?

Comment: that seems wrong. Please cite your source.

Comment: When the input is a step function, the harmonic analysis of it contains _all_ harmonics.